# XSLT: Return the value of a specific child if it is present in one of the parents' in ancestor tree

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML with the structure similar to below.

```
<root>
    <randomElement>..</randomElement>
    <EFFECT>..</EFFECT>
    <parent2>
        <randomElement>..</randomElement>
        <EFFECT>..</EFFECT>
        <parent>
            <randomElement>..</randomElement>
            <EFFECT>..</EFFECT>
            <randomElement>..</randomElement>
            <ITEM>..</ITEM>
        </parent>
    </parent2>
</root>
```

> Note: there can be any number of `<randomElement>`s at the places
>   where it's specified.

So, right now, my pointer is at the `<ITEM>` tag. I need to return the value inside of the `<EFFECT>` tag, but, here's the catch.

**If it's present**, I must return the value of the `<EFFECT>` tag which is inside `<parent>` tag. If it's not present there, I must return value of `<EFFECT>` tag which is inside the `<parent2>` tag. Again, if it is not present there too, I need to finally return the value of the `<EFFECT>` tag which is inside `<root>`. The `<EFFECT>` inside the `<root>` will always be present and there can be any number of parents for the `<ITEM>` element.

Sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: Use Xpath. Relatively moving from ITEM tag. It will go like this : *//ITEM/preceding-sibling::EFFECT/text()*

Comment: The first answer by Tomalak worked for me. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go to any `<ITEM>`, this is sufficient.

```
//ITEM
```

Now, `<EFFECT>` is a sibling to `<ITEM>`, i.e. it's on the same level. Another way of thinking about siblings is that they are children of the same parent.

In fact, all `<EFFECT>` elements in question are children of some ancestor of `<ITEM>`. This means we can move upwards along the `ancestor::` axis and grab all those ancestor elements in one step:

```
//ITEM/ancestor::*
```

This will give us `<parent>`, `<parent2>` and `<root>`, in this order.

And from *those* we only need to take one step down to grab all `<EFFECT>` elements:

```
//ITEM/ancestor::*/EFFECT
```

This will give us three `EFFECT` elements, this time again in document order (only the `ancestor::` type of axis works inside out).

We are interested in the last one of those, because this will be closest to the `<ITEM>` we started from. The `last()` function will help here:

```
(//ITEM/ancestor::*/EFFECT)[last()]
```

The parentheses around the path are necessary, because otherwise the condition (`[last()]`) is tested on every `<EFFECT>` individually, and each one of them is the last one of its kind for its parent, giving us three matches. The parentheses make it so that first a node-set of three `<EFFECT>` elements is constructed and *then* the last one is taken, giving us only one match.

When you already currently are at the `<ITEM>` element, the relative version of the path selects the last effect for that particular item:

```
(ancestor::*/EFFECT)[last()]
```